# How to merge an 8bit and a 16bit pcm file into separate audio channels in android

Tags: android, audio, merge, wav, pcm

I know there's been many similar questions and I read many of them but I couldn't make it work. as I said in the title, I have one 8bit and one 16bit pcm mono file which I want to merge them into one stereo wave file but in separate channels, one in the left and one in the right channel.

So far I've done as following but no matter what I do, two problems occur:
1- I can't write them in separate channels in the output file.
2- one of the files would be written like noises (whether "RECORDER_BPP" is 8 or 16)

my code :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int channels = 2;
            RECORDER_BPP = 16;
            int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
            int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(maxCaptureRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            byte[] data = new byte[minBufferSize];
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

            try {
                FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(rawAudio1);
                FileInputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(rawAudio2);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(wavAudio);
                long totalAudioLen = in1.getChannel().size();
                long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

                WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                        longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

                while(in1.read(data) != -1){
                    out.write(data);

                    //2nd channel ?! // unsuccessful
                    in2.read(data);
                    out.write(data);
                }

                in1.close();
                in2.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EEE-2ch", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}).start();
```

and here's the header part :

```
private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (channels * RECORDER_BPP / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = (byte) RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Stereo PCM data is interleaved (L R L R L R, etc), so you need to read/write one sample at a time. And for the 8-bit sample you need to apply some scaling if you want to preserve its loudness.

Comment: @Michael thanks, but could you give me some sample codes on how to do these ? I honestly have no experience on working with audio files and didn't quite understand what you said. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The output data needs to be interleaved, meaning you need to read a single sample from in1, write it to the output, and then read a single sample from in2 and write that to the output. Since in2 is 8-bit audio you need to read the 8-bit sample and then write out 16-bits.

```
byte[] data = new byte[2];
while(in1.read(data) != -1) { // read 2 bytes
    out.write(data);          // write 2 bytes (L)
    in2.read(data, 0, 1);     // read 1 byte
    data[1] = 0;              // set the other byte to zero
    // if this is the wrong byte order then do this
    // data[1] = data[0];
    // data[0] = 0;
    out.write(data);          // write 2 bytes (R)
}
```

This code is assumes that in1 is the file with 16-bit audio. If that is wrong then you'll need to rework it a bit.

Comment: It actually did separate left and right channels but the channel which the 8bit file was written to is complete noise. It seems that it happens because I set RECORDER_BPP=16 during writing to wav file. I changed the byte order like you said, but the other byte is empty and writes nothing. I checked the pcm files and they're ok. any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm don't quite understand what you mean by the other byte is empty. What you need to do for the second channel is read a single byte and then write it out as two bytes by left shifting.  So if the sample value in the file were 0x43, then you are writing out 0x4300 - voila 8-bit value turns into 16-bit value.

Comment: you said "if this is the wrong byte order then do this...". this actually wrote something as oppose to the first try data[1] = 0, but it was just noise. it does make the size two times bigger though. if I convert it to wave using RECORDER_BPP=8 this file would be written ok but the other file (16bit) would be written all noise. there's something wrong but I can't find out what.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is odd.  You read/write too many bytes at once. You also fail to check if reading from one of the input file fails....

Also, 8 bit pcm samples are usually unsigned, but pcm is usually signed.  You must convert your 8 bit value so the signs match.  I have included both cases in the code examples.  Pick the one that matches your input samples signedness.

```
byte[] data = new byte[minBufferSize];  // this is way too big for interlacing sample by sample.
while(in1.read(data) != -1){
    out.write(data);

    in2.read(data);  // <-- This could fail. 
    out.write(data);
}
```

Here's a way to handle this kind of problems.  Solution 1, no amplification of 8 bit value.

```
byte[] stereo_pair = new byte[4];  // a 16bit pcm stereo pair has only 4 bytes.
while (in1.read(stereo_pair, 0, 2)) // read two bytes from 16 bits pcm file.
{
    if (!in2.read(stereo_pair, 2, 1))  // read one byte from 8 bit file.
    {
        if (/*is unsigned 8 bit value*/)  // make it zero if error.
            stereo_pair[2] = 128;            
        else
            stereo_pair[2] = 0;
    }

    // we have to do some processing on that 8bit value.
    // If it's unsigned, we have to make it signed, then sign extend it.
    if (/*is unsigned 8 bit value*/)
    {
        stereo_pair[2] += 128; // this will offset the byte to make it signed
    }
    // we now have to sign extend the value
    if (stereo_pair[2] >= 127)
        stereo_pair[3] = 0xFF;
    else
        stereo_pair[3] = 0;

    // our stereo sample is ready to write.
    out.write(stereo_pair);
}
```

Solution 2, amplification of 8 bit value.

```
byte[] stereo_pair = new byte[4];  // a stereo pair has only 4 bytes.
while (in1.read(stereo_pair, 0, 2)) // read two bytes from 16 bits pcm file.
{
    // the only differences are that we read the byte at a different offset
    // in our stereo buffer, effectively multiplying the value by 256.
    // we also do not need to sign-extend the velue.

    if (!in2.read(stereo_pair, 3, 1))  // read one byte from 8 bit file.
    {
        if (/*is unsigned 8 bit value*/)  // make it zero if error.
            stereo_pair[3] = 128;            
        else
            stereo_pair[3] = 0;
    }

    // we have to do some processing on that 8bit value.
    // If it's unsigned, we have to make it signed
    if (/*is unsigned 8 bit value*/)
    {
        stereo_pair[3] += 128; // this will offset the byte to make it signed
    }

    stereo_pair[2] = 0; // I put this here for clarity, but it can be moved out of the loop.

    // our stereo sample is ready to write.
    out.write(stereo_pair);
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle the case when file in1 is shorter than file in2...